# Why Slingshot uploader callback is executed only once when uploading several files to S3?

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

I instantiate one `SlingShot uploader` per upload to handle several files upload.

To be more specific:

1. I render one template per upload in my `_.each` loop using `Blaze.renderWithData(Template.uploadItem, file, targetNode);`. See the loop below:

`'change .fileBrowse':function(event, template){
        _.each(event.currentTarget.files, function(file){
//...`

2. I keep track of the states of each upload state (except progress) in a local collection previously filled in the `_.each`  loop..
3. I instantiate `SlingShot uploader` in my `Template.uploadItem.created` function by attaching it to my template instance object (i.e. `this.uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( ...`)
4. I reach it using `Template.instance().uploader` as illustrated in this `progress` helper code

   `progress: function () {
     return Math.round(Template.instance().uploader.progress() * 100);
   }`

**The problem**: the uploader callback is only called once, when the last file has been posted. Everything else works fine, but I cant update my UI since the state is not updated in my local collection, as it should be when the callback is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved, it was a silly error: I used a public variable to store the file name, so it was stolen from one template to another.